# this keyword and protoypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, this

Hi I am trying to learn JavaScript and I come from a background of C++ so this is all pretty confusing to me. I have code that looks like this

```
var someArray = [];
nameCompare = function(this.first,this.second) 
{
    if(first.name == second.name)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(first.name < second.name)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

someArray.tempSort = function(){
    return this.sort(nameCompare);
};
var someOtherArray= Object.create(someArray);
someOtherArray.push({name: 'A', price: 3, rating: 2, distance: 2},
        {name: "B", price: 1, rating: 5, distance: 1},
        {name: 'C', price: 2, rating: 3, distance: 5},
        {name: 'D', price: 5, rating: 4, distance: 8});
console.log(someOtherArray.tempSort());
```

Im confused about the this keyword, since someArray gets its properties from someOtherArray and I want to sort by name I have no idea how to properly call the name property from someOtherArray.I understand the this keyword references the current object but i'm still lost. For some reason I keep getting an error about missing formal parameters, can I not pass this.first and this.second through the helper function?

Comment: `Object.create` probably does not what you want, even though it might work for you. If you want to create a copy of the array, use `someArray.slice()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `this.x` into your parameters, just pass variables (a and b below) like this:

```
var someArray = [];
nameCompare = function (a, b) {
    if (a.name == b.name) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Passing `this` into the parameters of your function is giving you the error. Check out [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) section on the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working version of what you are trying to do above: http://jsfiddle.net/TfM5U/

Some notes:

This line `nameCompare = function(this.first,this.second)` is defining a function and assigning it to the `nameCompare` variable. What you put inside the `()` are simply names you can use within the context of that function. So there is no reason to use `this.` here.

This line `var someOtherArray= Object.create(someArray);`. You can read more about `Object.create()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: thanks this helped a lot, but in tempSort once I return this.sort(nameCompare) i get back an object Object rather then a sorted array. why is this?

Comment: The sorted array is an object. In chrome dev tools you can inspect the object and have a look at each item. You can also try wrapping the array with `JSON.stringify(myArray)` to print the array out as a string.

Comment: var someOtherArray= Object.create(someArray) will indeed create a new object having the array as prototype. When writing to it, a new array (a copy) is created, and the initial array remains untouched. See here if in doubt : http://jsbin.com/OJEjAqe/1/